# Backing up source data files in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I expect 100's of data files in XML, Excels, delimited formats which I am converting to AVRO on a weekly basis. Would you suggest maintaining a backup of source files in original format in HDFS under a folder backup OR a folder under local file system, which is not HDFS.

The files are sourced from FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Once the conversion process is successful then since HDFS is hosting the AVRO files then it takes care of Backup assuming you setup the replication factor according to your needs. At this point, keeping the source files in HDFS is unnecessary. May be a Tape backup is what is optimal at this point.

Comment: What are the possible challenges for storing backups in HDFS? The storage cost is cheap and easily accessible... perhaps zip the files and store them at a location within HDFS

Comment: Some companies have huge amounts of data inflows and are supposed to have a backup until x number of years. I doesnt think it is a good idea to use HDFS as your backup storage mechanism even if the memory is cheap.

Comment: But can local file system be relied upon to store data backups? HDFS is more reliable